Im using rails graphql and vue apollo, my mutation is successful, however when i get all the updated queries they are all the same and not updated
I am using Rails with Graphql and Vue with Apollo
I was successfully able to create a Category however whenever I get all updated categories it does not return the updated category
here is the function I usually run
async getCategories() {
  this.loading = true;
  try {
    const response = await this.$apollo.query({
      query: gql`
        query Categories{
          categories {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      `,
    });
    // this.$store.commit('updateCategoriesState', {
    //   categories: response.data.categories,
    // });
    console.log(response.data.categories)
  } catch (error) {
    // turn this on for debugging
    // console.log(error)

  } finally { 
    this.loading = false;
  }
},

then this is my query_type for categories
# Category query field
field :categories, [Types::CategoryType], null: false

# Category resolver
def categories
  categories = Category.all
  categories
end


Do you see the expected result sent from your frontend in your browser devtools? How about what is received by the backend? The fact that you're using Rails and Apollo doesn't change anything to the actual payload sent and is as debuggable as any traditional HTTP call using REST. Also, make sure that the transaction is properly !updated in your ActiveRecord and that everything is set properly on the database side, with no errors in the server console. You can also use the GraphQL explorer when it comes down to inspecting the data. Lastly, be careful of the default cache coming with Apollo.

run in rails console Category.all to make sure you created any category in database
